# How can i most effectively calculate list /set difference

Tags: java, data-structures

I have an Object class : DemoObject.

DemoObject is like a list of some fooObjects.

fooObjects have a field called as "ID".

Now suppose I have two demoObject : demoObject1 and demoObject2. Now i want to check if there are some fooObject present in both demoObjects i.e in demoObject1 as well as in 2 then I probably removed it from demoObject1.

For checking fooObject from both demoObject I check with if fooObject "ID" field is same or not.

How I can accomplish it most effeciently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most idiomatic solution requires you to provide an `equals()` method in class `FooObject` which compares the objects based on their ID (or an appropriate `Comparator`).

Once you have this, just put the first list into a `Set` and use [`Set.removeAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to remove from the set all of its elements that are contained in list 2:

```
List<FooObject> demoObject1 = ...
List<FooObject> demoObject2 = ...

Set<FooObject> set1 = new HashSet(demoObject1);
set1.removeAll(demoObject2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set.retainAll()` method. I think it does what you need.